# как программно добавить опцию мультивыбора по клику мышки (без шифта) в ListBox?

Tags: c++, c++builder, radstudio, firemonkey

При использовании `ListBox1->MultiSelect = true;` я могу выделять несколько элементов только при зажатом <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Как настроить множественное выделение по простому щелчку мыши, без клавиатурных модификаторов?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно задать свойство `ListBox1->ExtendedSelect=false;`

Comment: в fmx нету такого свойства, к сожалению.

Comment: мда, последний тег не заметил

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, интересующее Вас свойство называется [`MultiSelectStyle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListBox.TCustomListBox.MultiSelectStyle). И хотя справка не изобилует подробностями:

> Embarcadero Technologies does not currently have any additional information. Please help us document this topic by using the Discussion page!

установка значения [`Extended`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListBox.TMultiSelectStyle) для него вроде бы решает проблему.